# Why does Android bluetooth scanner return the same device multiple times in the result, with two different MAC addresses?

Tags: android

I am working with bluetooth card readers. I noticed that at some points, the bluetooth scanner returns the same device but with a MAC address that differs only in the last digit. This is common for one particular manufacturer I am working with. Does anyone know why this occurs and if there's a way to scan to prevent the duplicate entry? As an example, I have one device that appears in the scan results as two devices with adddresses of:

2F:20:36:13:63:10 and 2F:20:36:13:63:11

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour (MAC addr + 1) is often used to indicate that the device is in firmware download mode. Does this usually happen when you start/reboot the card reader? Maybe it's in maintenance mode for a few seconds with the +1 MAC, and then switches to normal mode with the regular MAC.

If this is indeed the root cause, then there's nothing you can do about it except manually add code to ignore those devices with the higher-numbered MAC.

Comment: I consulted the manufacturter and a technical rep says the device broadcasts both BLE and bluetooth classic which accounts for the reason for two MAC addresses appearing.

Comment: I guess that my follow-up question would be is there a way to detect if the MAC address being broadcasted is from Bluetooth classic or BLE.

Comment: Or, more precisely, is it possible to filter out the BLE results from the scan when using the Android blueooth adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer. The `BluetoothDevice` object has a type property that indicates if it's classic, BLE, etc. I will use that in conjunction with my scanner.